# what is windows equivalent command to 'export USER_SUPPLIED_PASSWORD=pswd'

Tags: linux, windows, environment-variables

I am working on a GUI based application. In that, I need to fill several fields of password which I give same every time, since this is development environment. While using Linux, I can pass the command `export USER_SUPPLIED_PASSWORD=pswd`.

But I am not able to find the same provision in Windows.

Comment: `set USER_SUPPLIED_PASSWORD=pswd`