# React App ignores NODE_ENV of the production mode

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, production-environment

I'm fairly new to React and I've built a client side react app using webpack as module bundler and npm. It works smoothly in development with Webpack devServer. While in production, I've used express as a server. When running at localhost:8080, it displays fine but I get these warnings. I set up the NODE_ENV='production', but still same warnings.

[image: warning when using react app in production mode]

Here is my production configuration file

production.config.js

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");



const config ={
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',


  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './client/main.js'
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    publicPath:'/'

  },


  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              //query: { sourceMap: false },
              options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader'
            }
          ]

        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico|\.woff$|\.ttf$|\.wav$|\.mp3$)$/i,
        use: ['file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]',
          'image-webpack-loader']

      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'

      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [  
    //index.html custom template
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Index',
      template: './index.html'

    }),
     new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(
      { 
        'process.env': 
      { 
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production') } 
    }
    ),

    //extract css files
    new ExtractTextPlugin({filename:"styles.css",disable:false,allChunks:true}),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: false,
      mangle: true,
      beautify:false,
      compress: {
        warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
        pure_getters: true,
        unsafe: true,
        unsafe_comps: true,
        screw_ie8: true
      },
      output: {
        comments: false
      }  
  })


  ]
};

module.exports=config
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --colors",
    "prod": "npm run build && node deploy.js",
    "build": "webpack --config production.config.js --progress --colors"
       }
```

//dependencies are omitted
    }

Comment: Try `"build": "export NODE_ENV=production && NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config production.config.js --progress --colors"`. You might need NODE_ENV to be set to 'production' in the shell as well, which those extra commands will do.

Comment: Just tried your solution but it throws export as not a recognized command. my os is windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212411/what-is-windows-equivalent-command-to-export-user-supplied-password-pswd. Apparently the equivalent Windows command is 'set'.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're using the EnvironmentPlugin in webpack, but with DefinePlugin syntax. Take a look here: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/

Comment: It still gives same warning after I used `EnviromentalPlugin`. what I'm confused about is that my `app.bundle.js` has 300kb in size compared to 1.9mega in development. so apparently the production works but it seems `node_env` is completely ignored in shell or in production config file? or is there another possible explanation...

Answer (score 3):

Try using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

I believe there is a problem with setting NODE_ENV=production in windows command prompts which it solves.

Usage example:

Build script:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

//...

plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(env)
    }
  })
]

//...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I solved it by setting `process.env` to `process.env.NODE_ENV`and putting `set NODE_ENV='production'` with quotation and it worked. I'll upvote your answer since its closer to the fix i made.